# Can I get pickle.dump to expose a file-like object?

Tags: python, pickle

I want to pickle my objects compressed with [snappy-python](https://github.com/andrix/python-snappy). Because these objects are large I want to use something streaming -- i.e. pickle.dump, not pickle.dumps.

Unfortunately, the snappy and pickle APIs don't seem particularly compatible:

```
snappy.stream_compress(src, dst, blocksize=65536)
pickle.dump(obj, file, protocol=None)
```

Any thoughts on what magic I would need for something like `snappy.stream_compress(pickle.dump_magic(obj), dst)` to work similarly to what `pickle.dump(obj, dst)` does today?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest would be to `pickle.dump` to a file, and then `snappy.stream_compress` the file.

```
def snappy_pickle_dump(obj, f):
    tmpf = ...
    with open(tmpf, 'wb') as F:
        pickle.dump(obj, F)
    with open(f, 'wb') as OUT:
        with open(tmpf, 'rb') as IN:
            snappy.stream_compress(IN, OUT)
    os.remove(tmpf)
```

If you must avoid storing the entire uncompressed dump, you can have one thread `pickle.dump`ing the object into a `StringIO` object, and another thread `snappy.stream_compress`ing it.

Comment: I agree that this is probably simplest, but it would be nice to avoid the extra read/write pass if possible (threading, maybe, since this piece should be mostly IO bound).

Answer (score 0):

I'm only 10 years late to this party, but this works:

```py
import snappy
import pickle

def snappy_pickle(obj: object, path: str) -> None:
    """
    Pickle an object to a file using snappy compression
    :param obj: The object to pickle
    :param path: The path to the file to write to
    """
    b = snappy.compress(pickle.dumps(obj))
    with open(path, 'wb') as fp:
        fp.write(b)

def snappy_unpickle(path) -> object:
    """
    Unpickle an object from a file using snappy compression
    :param path: The path to the file to read from
    """
    with open(path, 'rb') as fp:
        b = fp.read()
        return pickle.loads(snappy.decompress(b))
```